# URL rank checker API for google popularity

Tags: seo, pagerank, popularity, google-trends

I am trying to find the rank of a given url/domain for google search popularity from an API.I have found one such project in GitHub that gives the same but i am not sure about the reliability and accuracy of the results it is returning me(https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats). If anyone has come across with other alternatives or libraries for the google site popularity please share with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't expose an API for "find[ing] the rank of a given url/domain for google search".

> Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide.

http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/

Comment: ok, but is there any way to find keyword popularity on google?Like Google trends expose any api to find the popularity of any keyword.

Comment: If you want to find keyword popularity, use the keyword tool: https://adwords.google.com/ko/KeywordPlanner/Home - but this has nothing to do with coding!